Trouble creating a trigger function in Supabase for updating a field in another table
I'm currently working on a project using Supabase, and I'm having trouble creating a trigger function to update a field in another table.
Here's the scenario:
I have two tables in my Supabase database:

Employee table with columns: id, name, and team_id.
Team table with columns: code, name, employeeCount.

I want the employeeCount field in the Team table to be updated whenever an employee is added to or removed from a specific team.
I tried creating a trigger function in Supabase to achieve this, but I'm encountering syntax errors or issues with the trigger itself. Here's the function I attempted to create:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_employee_count()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        UPDATE Team
        SET employeeCount = employeeCount + 1
        WHERE code = NEW.team_id;

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        UPDATE Team
        SET employeeCount = employeeCount - 1
        WHERE code = OLD.team_id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

When I tried to create this function, I received an error message indicating a syntax error near the CREATE statement.
Could someone please help me identify what might be wrong with my function or suggest an alternative approach to achieve the desired outcome? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Having the employee count in the employee's table is probably not the best idea, and instead, you should have a separate table that references the employee's table and count the number of associated rows dynamically. SQL can handle this very effieicnetly, and you will always keep your data integrity.
